# How to turn off .NET 4.5 features on CSharpCodeProvider?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using CSharpCodeProvider to compile assembly. I want to get errors when user using features and classes from .NET Framework versions above 4.0.

For example, if run this code on machine with installed 4.5 version .NET framework, CSharpCodeProvider compiles successfully with .NET 4.5 APIs(e.g. System.Reflection.ReflectionContext)

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } };
var cs = new CSharpCodeProvider(options);
var compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
var r = cs.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    compilerParams,
    "namespace Sample {public class SampleClass{private System.Reflection.ReflectionContext a;}}");
```

Anyone any idea how I can specify to use the only 4.0 version for compile?

Comment: .NET 4.0 is no longer supported. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. 4+ versions are binary replacements so you are probably running on a later version already

Comment: In other words, if that code generates 4.5 features it's because .NET 4.0 has been replaced by a newer version already

Comment: System.CodeDom always targets the installed version of .NET 4.x and the reference assemblies come from c:\windows\microsoft.net.  So there is no option to select a different version number, you have to make sure that the desired one is available by targeting your own program high enough.  Or, I guess, in this case by forcing the user to downgrade.  He's not going to do that.

Comment: If you're interested in particular language version not .Net version,
you can try passing [`/langversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/langversion-compiler-option) to `CompilerParamters`.

Comment: When you creating project in Visual Studio, you can choose .NET framework version, so you can not build 4.0 .net project with 4.5 features. Any ideas how they do it?

Comment: /langversion does not solve my problem, because you can still use .net features and user must be able to use other versions of language

Answer (score 1):

The way to specifically target the .NET 4.0 Framework shape is to do what MSBuild does when resolving assembly references in .NET 4.0 projects by default, target the reference assemblies deployed by the Windows SDK (which is installed by VS). The reference assemblies installed to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0 represent the public surface area of the Framework binaries for .NET 4.0 - referencing these binaries will let your app target the subset of .NET 4.5 available on systems with only .NET 4.0 installed.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783278/compilerversion-is-not-being-taken-into-account-v4-0-in-a-machine-with-net-4-5-installed

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to link another mscorlib.dll, using the /nostdlib option.

```
List<String> references = new List<string>();

String mscorlib = Path.Combine(              
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
    @"Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
);

references.Add(mscorlib);
// Add other references...

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<String,String> {{"CompilerVersion", "v4.0"}});

var parameters = new CompilerParameters(references.ToArray(), "MyApp.exe");
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
parameters.CompilerOptions = "/nostdlib";              

var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
    @"using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""CLR Version: "" + Environment.Version);
        }
    }");
```

Comment: That's a 2.0 library, not 4.0. There's no separate 4.0 library - versions after 4.0 are binary replacements. Install a newer one and you are running on it even if the project is marked 4.0. Besides, 4.0 is no longer supported.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I fixed but it won't work anyway. NET 4.5 is a true in-place update for version 4.0... so I'm afraid but there are probably no solutions to this issue.

Comment: When you creating project in Visual Studio, you can choose .NET framework version, so you can not build 4.0 .net project with 4.5 features. Any ideas how they do it?